# how to Pass an inequality into a function as a variable, then evaluate it?

Tags: python

```
def bubble_up(heap, inequality):
  print heap, 'bubbling up', heap[-1]
  heap_length = len(heap)
  position = heap_length - 1 #heap_length
  parent = int(heap_length/2) - 1
  print 'parent =', heap[parent]
  while heap[position] inequality heap[parent]:
```

Well that doesn't work!
I want to pass an inequality in, and have it evaluated, and I want it to be clear what I've done in 6 months time.
Also I want it to be fast.  If it's quantumly better just to write two functions with a changed sign, please shout at me why this is.

Comment: what do you mean by  inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your `bubble_up` function to call `inequality` as a function:

```
while inequality(heap[position], heap[parent]):
```

And then pass in a *function* that evaluates the desired inequality.

You can use Python's `lambda` keyword to define the inequality function right in your call to `bubble_up` without needing to give it a name:

```
bubble_up(my_heap, lambda x, y: x < y)
```

Or you can use functions already defined for you in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module:

```
import operator

bubble_up(my_heap, operator.lt)
```

if you are usually going to use a particular inequality, use it as a default in your function definition:

```
def bubble_up(heap, inequality=operator.lt):
    # and so on
```

Comment: Thanks kindall.  Function must be the way to do it.  Appreciate the fullness of your answer.